# BeautifulSoup incomplete children with find_all

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I am traying to scrap the nested div instances under the "product-tech-section-row" class from the following HTML script:

```
<h2 class="product-tech-section-title">
    Présentation de la TV SAMSUNG UE49MU9005</h2>

<div class="product-tech-section-row">
    <div>
        Désignation</b> :
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>SAMSUNG UE49MU9005</b> (UE 49MU9005 TXXC)<br><br>Plus d'informations sur les <a             href="http://www.lcd-compare.com/info-tv-led-samsung.htm" title="TV Samsung : informations et statistiques">TV LED Samsung</a><br><a href="http://www.lcd-compare.com/tv-liste-122.htm?tv_label=7,8" title="Liste des TV 4K">Voir les TV 4K (Ultra HD ou Quad HD)</a></div>
</div>


<div class="product-tech-section-row">
    <div>
        Date de sortie (approx.)</b> :
    </div>
    <div>
        Mars 2017</div>
</div>
```

However, using find_all() will only extract the first div child (only Désignation, SAMSUNG UE... does not appear) as it is shown in my code below. Am I missing something? Help will be much appreciated.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#Allowing access to the website (personal use)
prod_url="http://www.lcd-compare.com/televiseur-SAMUE49MU9005-SAMSUNG-UE49MU9005.htm"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(prod_url,headers=hdr)
prod_html=uReq(req)

#Parsing the technical details
tec_list = prod_soup.find_all("div",{"class","product-tech-section-row"})

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#However, this is what I am getting:
>>>print(tec_list[0])
<div class="product-tech-section-row">
<div>
Désignation</div></div>

>>>print(tec_list[0].findChildren())
[<div>
 Désignation<\div>]
```

Comment: Try print(tec_list[1]) this will get you the "SAMSUNG UE49MU9005" result. Keep in mind that find_all() returns a list of the scarped elements, which is stored in tec_list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately print(tec_list[1]) will only return "Date de sortie (approx.)", which is the following "product-tech-section-row" class

Comment: Hi p404 please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason why you can't scrap the nested elements is because the website you access is heavily rendered by Javascript.

I've used selenium to verify if that was the case, and I was able to parse the nested elements normally with no problems.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chromeOptions = Options()  
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
url = 'http://www.lcd-compare.com/televiseur-SAMUE49MU9005-SAMSUNG-UE49MU9005.htm'
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
tec_list = soup.findAll("div",{"class","product-tech-section-row"})

print(tec_list[0])
```

Output:

```
<div class="product-tech-section-row">
<div>
Désignation :
</div>
<div>
<b>SAMSUNG UE49MU9005</b> (UE 49MU9005 TXXC)<br/><br/>Plus d'informations sur les <a data-hasqtip="139" href="http://www.lcd-compare.com/info-tv-led-samsung.htm" oldtitle="TV Samsung : informations et statistiques" title="">TV LED Samsung</a><br/><a data-hasqtip="141" href="http://www.lcd-compare.com/tv-liste-122.htm?tv_label=7,8" oldtitle="Liste des TV 4K" title="">Voir les TV 4K (Ultra HD ou Quad HD)</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ali! Your suggestion worked perfectly fine. By the way, I wanted to ask you if there are some other libraries that can do the same job , but without involving a browser. It would be so that this kind of code can easily be added into a web API.

Comment: @p404, Sorry for the late reply. I don't really know about any other library that would accomplish your goal. But keep searching.

Comment: Hi Ali, I did some research and found that the PhantomJS headless browser could get it done. It can also be loaded from selenium webdriver like: driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(). I hope you can also find it useful in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I  actually new about PhantomJS but I thought you wanted an alternative for Selenium. I'm glad you found a solution. Also there is a way to run a headless browser using the ChromeDriver.

Comment: I just edited my answer to see how you can use headless support for the ChromeDriver.

Comment: That setting looks very interesting, thanks for the update!

Comment: No problem @p404 :)